# Regressive generic type inference

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

[Demo code in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IService%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isOverriden%3CT%20extends%20BaseService%2C%20U%20extends%20IService%3E(target%3A%20T%2C%20prop%3A%20keyof%20T%20%7C%20keyof%20U)%3A%20prop%20is%20keyof%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20prop%20in%20target%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20BaseService%20implements%20IService%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20readonly%20origin%3A%20IService)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%09static%20wrap%3CU%20extends%20IService%2C%20T%20extends%20BaseService%3E(this%3A%20%7B%20new(origin%3A%20U)%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20origin%3A%20U)%3A%20T%20%26%20U%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20Proxy(new%20this(origin)%20as%20T%20%26%20U%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09get(target%3A%20T%20%26%20U%2C%20prop%3A%20keyof%20T%20%7C%20keyof%20U)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(isOverriden(target%2C%20prop))%20return%20target%5Bprop%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09return%20target.origin%5Bprop%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D)%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SimpleService%20implements%20IService%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MongoService%20implements%20IService%20%7B%0D%0A%09log()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log('Hello%201')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20VerificationService%20extends%20BaseService%20%7B%0D%0A%09log2()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log('Hello%202')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20serviceInferedIncorrectly%20%3D%20VerificationService.wrap(new%20MongoService())%3B%20%2F%2F%20VerificationService%20%26%20IService%0D%0Aconst%20serviceInferedCorrectly%20%3D%20VerificationService.wrap(new%20SimpleService())%3B%20%2F%2F%20VerificationService%20%26%20SimpleService%0D%0Aconst%20serviceSpecified%20%3D%20VerificationService.wrap%3CMongoService%2C%20VerificationService%3E(new%20MongoService())%3B%20%2F%2F%20VerificationService%20%26%20MongoService%0D%0A%0D%0A)

I'm trying to create a more dynamic implementation of the decorator pattern using the [ES6's `Proxy` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

The general idea is that I have an `IService` interface and a `BaseService` abstract class. The abstract class has an `origin` property that's an instance of `IService` and all the unimplemented calls are forwarded to this object. `BaseService` exposes a static method `wrap` that creates a new instance of the decorator and sets it's origin to the service instance provided as a parameter.

Functionality of this approach is not a problem, the problem comes when I try to specify the types. For some reason, when I try to decorate the `MongoService` with a `VerificationService`, the origin type is reduced to `IService` and the return value is of type `VerificationService & IService` instead of the desired `VerificationService & MongoService`.

My question is whether this is intended behavior because of some covariance/contra-variance issues the code could lead to or if it's a bug and the compiler just doesn't know that the type of the parameter is MongoService. Please notice that when I try to decorate an instance of a class that doesn't add any properties, the type is correctly inferred (line 37)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why this happens, but if you look at the type of `wrapper` and the constructor for `VerificationService` (inherited from `BaseService`) we get an idea of why this might be. The parameter to the constructor is `ISerivce` not a generic type, so the simplest assumption would be to infer `U` to `IService` in `wrap`, and the second parameter to `wrap` satisfies `IService` so it all works fine, no reason to look further.

The simplest solution would be to change the type of `wrapper`, since the argument can be any service anyway:

```
static wrap<U extends IService, T extends BaseService>(this: { new(origin: IService): T }, origin: U): T & U {
    return new Proxy(new this(origin) as T & U, {
        get(target: T & U, prop: keyof T | keyof U) {
            if (isOverriden(target, prop)) return target[prop];
            return target.origin[prop];
        }
    })
}
// All work as expected
const serviceInferedIncorrectly = VerificationService.wrap(new MongoService()); // VerificationService & MongoService
const serviceInferedCorrectly = VerificationService.wrap(new SimpleService()); // VerificationService & SimpleService
const serviceSpecified = VerificationService.wrap<MongoService, VerificationService>(new MongoService()); // VerificationService & MongoService
```